# Having trouble overwriting squarespace-set attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, squarespace

I'm trying to overwrite some squarespace code with jquery. I want the blog to show all entries in one column, at the moment it is using two.

I can add new attributes and classes to the element, so I know that the selector works.

My code (in the footer):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.BlogList--posts-excerpt').attr("data-columns", "1");
});
```

The element I want to change:

```
<section class="BlogList BlogList--posts-excerpt sqs-blog-list clear" data-columns="2">
```

---

To summarize:

Expected:

```
<section class="BlogList BlogList--posts-excerpt sqs-blog-list clear" data-columns="1">
```

Actual:

```
<section class="BlogList BlogList--posts-excerpt sqs-blog-list clear" data-columns="2">
```

I think the problem is that squarespace executes parts of their stylistic code after jquery runs, so my custom code gets overwritten.
Does anyone know how to overwrite this behavior?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

To execute after Squarespace's own scripts, try:

```
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
  $('.BlogList--posts-excerpt').attr("data-columns", "1");
});
```